# Validate invalid parameters

Tags: php, validation, laravel-5

Using laravel validator I am trying to invalidate data if an attribute was given.
So the opposite of the `required` rule.

Current rules

```
$rules = [
        'email_address' => 'required|max:255|Email|unique:users,email'
];
```

Not Valid

```
{
    "username": "Perry55",
    "email": "aHowe@Roob.com",
    "password": "GR1OEcNWwO"
}
```

Valid

```
{
    "email": "aHowe@Roob.com"
}
```

Comment: you dont need to invalidate anything, if you want any attribute not insertable exclude it from fillable array in your eloquent model file.

Comment: @NehalHasnayeen actually I want to differentiate bretween create and update validation, in create a property might be fillable but not in update

Comment: You can rely on conditionals such as `$request->method()` or something like `$request->is('*/create')`.

Comment: @user2094178 that lets me validate the request type, which is not needed. The post only calls the store method. I simply need to make sure some data is not passed, its an api and I only want a post to update certain fields. I could manually check if the field exists, but that defeats the purpose of the validator.

Comment: If it is a resource controller the request method will differentiate from store to update, if not you can check for `$request->is('*/store')`.

Comment: @user2094178 Yes but if an extra parameter is posted it goes to the database. I want to validate input so that all other parameters that are not in the rule set to be invalid and the request rejected. My update ruleset only validates the "email" field. If someone passed along an "email" it would go to the database. NehalHasnayeen suggested the fillable array, but can I have different fillable arrays for create and post.

Comment: Ok, you should avoid mass assigment in this scenario and rely on `$guarded`. You can also try something like `'username' => 'sometimes|required_with:'. substr(md5(uniqid()), 0, 15)`, when updating.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use different $fillable property for create and update method, use fillable method eloquent model to set fillable column like this
in create method

```
$model->fillable(['name', 'email', 'password']); //$model is instanceof Model class
```

in store method

```
$model->fillable(['email']);
```

And you have to use eloquent model to update not the query builder, because query builder will ignore your $fillable property & insert everything

```
$model = Model::find($id);
$model->update($request->all());  //$request is instanceof Request class

Model::where('id', $id)->update($request->all());
```

Another way is if someone using html form for updating is to ignore the unwanted input like this

$model->update($request->except(['input_field_name']));